# Why is Python's .decode('cp037') not working on specific binary array?

Tags: python, binary, byte, arrays, ibm-midrange

When printing out DB2 query results I'm getting the following error on column 'F00002' which is a binary array.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using the following line:

`print result[2].decode('cp037')`

...just as I do the first two columns where the same code works fine. Why is this not working on the third column and what is the proper decoding/encoding?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you have in those binaries and why do you have to print them as text?

Comment: When you ask "what is the proper decoding/encoding", how do you expect anyone to know that? Maybe if you showed us the actual bytes we could guess… but with nothing to go on besides the fact that it's 245 bytes of BINARY data that we can't see, there's nothing to guess with.

Comment: @PauloBu: It is inventory information from a db2 on an as/400 system. I need the text so I can relay information to an online mysql database.

Comment: @abarnert: Here is what prints out if simply print result[2] as is - http://i.imgur.com/kT5cJMW.jpg ... result[2] = the F00002 from a 'SELECT F00001, K00001, F00002 FROM QS36F."SH.ITEM"' db2 query.

Comment: @user1645914 do you have any idea on what encoding does db2 use for this kind of columns?

Comment: @user1645914: I think you accepted the wrong answer. If `print type(result[2])` gives you `bytearray` (as you said in a comment), then the problem is _not_ that `result[2]` is already Unicode, it's just a problem printing out the properly-decoded result.

Comment: @PauloBu: db2 doesn't do any encoding on BINARY columns; that's the whole point. But what's actually _in_ those columns appears to be text encoded as EBCDIC/cp037, and that's what the OP is trying to recover.

Comment: @user1645914: Along abarnert's line of questioning (in his answer and comments), what do you get when you `print repr(result[2])`?

Comment: @JohnY I get a bunch of byte arrays: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gvmcRZma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the error is about *encoding* to ASCII, not about *decoding* from cp307. But you're not asking it to encode anywhere, so why is this happening?

Well, there are actually two possible places this could go wrong, and we can't know which of them it is without some help from you.

---

First, if your `result[2]` is already a `unicode` object, calling `decode('cp037')` on it will first try to `encode` it with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is usually `'ascii'`, so that it has something to decode. So, instead of getting an error saying "Hey, bozo, I'm already decoded", you get an error about encoding to ASCII failing. (This may seem very silly, but it's useful for a handful of codecs that can decode `unicode`->`unicode` or `unicode`->`str`, like ROT13 and quoted-printable.)

If this is your problem, the solution is to not call `decode`. You've presumably already decoded the data somewhere along the way to this point, so don't try to do it again. (If you've decoded it *wrong*, you need to figure out where you decoded it and fix that to do it right; re-decoding it after it's already wrong won't help.)

---

Second, passing a Unicode string to `print` will automatically try to `encode` it with (depending on your Python version) either `sys.getdefaultencoding()` or `sys.stdout.encoding`. If Python has failed to guess the right encoding for your console (pretty common on Windows), or if you're redirecting your script's stdout to a file instead of printing to the console (which means Python can't possibly guess the right encoding), you can end up with `'ascii'` even in `sys.stdout.encoding`.

If this is your problem, you have to explicitly specify the right encoding for your console (if you're lucky, it's in `sys.stdout.encoding`), or the encoding you want for the text file you're redirecting to (probably `'utf-8'`, but that's up to you), and explicitly `encode` everything you `print`.

---

So, how do you know which one of these it is?

Simple. `print type(result[2])` and see whether it's a `unicode` or a `str`. Or break it up into two pieces: `x = result[2].decode('cp037')` and then `print x`, and see which of the two raises. Or run in a debugger. You have all kinds of options for debugging this, but you have to do something.

Of course it's also possible that, once you fix the first one, you'll immediately run into the second one. But now you know how to deal with that to.

---

Also, note that cp037 is EBCDIC, one of the few encodings that Python knows about that *isn't* ASCII-compatible. In fact, `'\xe3'` is EBCDIC for the letter `T`.

Comment: print type(result[2]) = <type 'bytearray'>

Comment: print type(result[2].decode('cp037')) = <type 'unicode'> (of course)

Comment: IBM i (AS/400, iSeries, etc.) is natively EBCDIC which is why I use decode('cp037').

Comment: @user1645914: OK, so it's _not_ the first error (the `decode`, as explained by alko), but the `print` part. Have you read the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)? If you're on Windows, and Python 2.7, and your Windows OEM code page is some ASCII superset but not UTF-8, most likely the answer is to add a `.encode(<something>)` to each `print` statement, where that `<something>` depends on what the OEM code page is.

Comment: @user1645914: Yeah, I assumed from the fact that (a) you were using DB2 in 2013 and (b) you had EBCDIC data in 2013 that some IBM big iron was involved… Anyway, it looks like your DB2 driver isn't decoding or re-encoding for you, so you're doing that part right; you just have the more general "Windows console sucks in Python 2.x" problem.

Comment: I'm not thrilled about using archaic technology but the job more than pays for itself. I just run into crummy errors. And yeah, one work station -- this one -- is using Windows XP :o). X-mf-P...

Comment: @user1645914: Honestly, I'd rather deal with EBCDIC than Latin-1 derivatives. (When you make an encoding mistake, EBCDIC makes it impossible to miss, instead of letting all your tests pass and months after release discovering that it blows up when someone types a Euro symbol because you assumed CP1252 == Latin-1.) Of course an all-UTF-8 world would be even better, but that's still years off (thanks mainly to Microsoft, but also a few Japanese producers).

Comment: @abarnert: I think in this case it's not so much that the Windows console sucks but that there is actual nontext data mixed in. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `result[2]` is already unicode:

```
>>> u'\xe3'.decode('cp037')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'\xe3'.encode('cp037')
'F'
```

In fact, as pointed out @abarnert in comments, in python 2.x `decode` being called for unicode object is performed in two steps:

- encoding to string with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`,
- then decoding back to unicode

i.e., you statement is translated as:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> u'\xe3'.encode('ascii').decode('cp037')
```

and the error you get is from the first part of expression, `u'\xe3'.encode('ascii')`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in Python 2.x, you _can_ call `decode` on a Unicode object, it's just a very silly thing to do—it automatically encodes it using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (which is usually `'ascii'`) so it can then `decode` the result with the specified character set. That's why the error is so mysterious.

Comment: Even more fun, because he's passing it to `print`, it's actually more like `u'\xe3'.encode('ascii').decode('cp037').encode('ascii')`… But that's assuming that `result[2]` actually _is_ Unicode, which we don't know; it's possible that he's doing `'F'.decode('cp037').encode('ascii')`

Answer (score 1):

All right, so as @abarnert established, you don't really have a Unicode problem, per se. The Unicode only enters the picture when trying to `print`.  After looking at [your data](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gvmcRZma), I can see that there is actually not just EBCDIC character data in there, but arbitrary binary data as well.  The data definitely seems columnar, so what we probably have here is a bunch of subfields all packed into the field called `F00002` in your example.  RPG programmers would refer to this as a *data structure*; it's akin to a C `struct`.

The `F00001` and `K00001` columns probably worked fine because they happen to contain only EBCDIC character data.

So if you want to extract the complete data from `F00002`, you'll have to find out (via documentation or some person who has the knowledge) what the subfields are.  Normally, once you've found that out, you could just use Python's `struct` module to quickly and simply unpack the data, but since the data comes from an IBM i, you may be faced with converting its native data types into Python's types.  (The most common of these would be *packed decimal* for numeric data.)

For now, you can still extract the character portions of `F00002` by decoding as before, but then explicitly choosing a new encoding that works with your output (display or file), as @abarnert suggested.  My recommendation is to write the values to a file, using `result[2].decode('cp037').encode('utf-8')` (which will produce a bunch of clearly not human-readable data interspersed with the text; you may be able to use that as-is, or you could use it to at least tell you *where* the text portions are for further processing).

---

**Edit:**

We don't have time to do all your work and research for you.  Things you need to just read up on and work out for yourself:

- IBM's packed decimal format (crash course: each digit takes up 4 bits using basic hexadecimal; with an additional 4 bits on the right for the sign, which is 'F' for positive and 'D' for negative; the whole thing zero-padded on the left if needed to fill out a whole number of bytes; decimal place is implied)
- IBM's zoned decimal format (crash course: each digit is 1 byte and is identical to the EBCDIC representation of the corresponding character; except that on the rightmost digit, the upper 4 bits are used for the sign, 'F' for positive and 'D' for negative; decimal place is implied)
- Python's `struct` module (doesn't automatically handle the above types; you have to use raw bytes for everything (type 's') and handle as needed)
- Possibly pick up some ideas (and code) for handling IBM packed and zoned decimals from the add-on [api2](https://bitbucket.org/buzzh/api2) module for [iSeriesPython 2.7](http://www.iseriespython.com) (in particular, check out the `iSeriesStruct` class, which is a subclass of `struct.Struct`, keeping in mind that the whole module is designed to be *running on* the iSeries, using iSeriesPython, and thus is *not necessarily usable as-is* from regular Python communicating with the iSeries via `pyodbc`).

Comment: This is what my QS36F."SH.ITEM" file with 65 sub-fields looks like: http://i.imgur.com/XDduyJy.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/8Cuiqui.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/GDF6DmY.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/yiHr1nx.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/CbwNj91.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/YgZbUrO.jpg ... how would I use struct to "quickly and simply unpack the data"?

Comment: @user1645914: Have you read the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) docs? It's pretty simple: If they're all fixed-width fields, you just write a format string that lists all the field types and widths in order, then `f00002_fields = struct.unpack(F00002_FORMAT_STRING, result[2])`. If they're variable-width, you need to `unpack_from` one at a time (e.g., first unpack the width, then use that as the number of characters to unpack as a string). Either way, you'll get EBCDIC strings (along with integers, etc.) that you have to `.decode`.

Comment: @user1645914: But just seeing a list of the columns isn't enough to know what the field types and widths are (except by some tedious reverse-engineering). You should have some way to get the definition of this report or something like that, which will tell you that, e.g., field 0 is a 16-bit unsigned int (it may not tell you that it's, say, big-endian, but that you can guess, and it should be true universally), field 3 is a 25-character fixed-width string, etc. From that, it will be easy to write.

Comment: @abarnert: Well, it's unlikely that any of the fields are "unsigned int" or the like. That's not the way DB2 for i generally rolls.  Especially in the System/36 environment (QS36F library). They will mostly be packed decimal, or zoned. So `struct` will offer no immediate help for numeric values, besides just chopping up the `bytearray` into `str` (byte strings) of the appropriate size. That's what I meant by having to converting native i types to Python.

Comment: @user1645914: The screenshots show a couple of leading columns (EACT1 and EITEM) that aren't subfields of F00002.  Perhaps those are F00001 and K00001?  I don't know.  But you do need to find out the overall size (in bytes) and the number of decimal places for each of the numeric subfields.  After you get past that, then you can worry about how to translate packed decimal data.  (A quick glance at the raw `bytearray` data looks to me like everything is either EBCDIC text or packed decimal.)

Comment: @JohnY: I'd still do it by taking one of the pure-Python extensible re-implementations of `struct` off PyPI (like [netstruct](https://github.com/stendec/netstruct), or the one that does bitfields that I can't remember the name of) and adding support for packed decimal. But your main point is the key—the first step to parsing the data is finding out what the data are, ideally by reading it somewhere rather than reverse engineering.

Comment: I am still stuck. Table SH.ITEM has three columns: F00001 (EACT1), K00001 (EITEM) and F00002 (69 sub fields). I decode the first two via .decode('cp037') no problem. I took the advice of @abarnert but cannot figure out struct. This is what I tried: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BPkugbqg . I put together a data field reference for SH.ITEM here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ruXLaGXR and put 100 rows of its data here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wg0SU0tz. When F00002 is decoded those longer text fields have varying lengths making this a semi difficult parse.

Comment: @user1645914: Unless those fields actually _are_ a native-endian 32-bit int, a 25-character string, a native IEEE float, etc., that `struct` format is not going to work. And, as John Y explained in the comments above, it's very unlikely that your numeric fields are native-endian 32-bit ints, etc.

Comment: @user1645914: Since you have the (sub)field definitions, at this point you have all the tools you need. See my edited answer.